# Как правильно завернуть console.log() в переменную?

Tags: javascript, консоль, firebug

Собсно задался вопросом укоротить конструкцию console.log() для удобства. Так как часто пользуюсь выводом на консоль firebug. 
Реализовал я это так:
    var cout = console.log;
    cout('It's great. But doesn't work in Chrome's console!');

Как вы поняли из строки вывода, в консоли хрома это дело не работает. Я так и не понял, в чем причина. Может вы объясните? Или подскажете другой способ сокращения?

Comment: да. Кстати, на днях как-то еще вот так пробовал делать:
function cout(x){
console.log(x);
}
Вроде бы так. Не помню. Этот способ я правда в хроме не проверял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var log  = function(msg){
                console.log ? console.log(msg) : alert(msg);
            }
    log('Где то пошло, что то не так')
```

Comment: А вообще может быть такая ситуация, что левая часть оператора : не исполнится?

Comment: Точно не знаю, в нашем мире может быть все, что угодно)

Comment: "бережёного бог бережёт" - сказала монашка, надевая презерватив на свечку :)

Answer (score 2):

```
window.c = function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

c('Тра-та-та..');
```